# How to change the Boolean between two similar Booleans in a column in dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, duplicates

I am working on dataframes with different sizes. I need to change the 'True' Boolean in a column in a dataframe to 'False' boolean  if the 'True' boolean found between two 'False' booleans at the same column in dataframe.

This is an example of one of dataframes:

df =

```
 index        DATE     S_N        A  timestamp  delta   time  \
0      7  2021-01-05  78          4 2021-01-05    NaT    NaN   
1      8  2021-01-07  78          3 2021-01-07 2 days   48.0   
2      9  2021-01-08  78          3 2021-01-08 1 days   24.0   
3     10  2021-01-10  78          3 2021-01-10 2 days   48.0   
4     11  2021-01-11  78          6 2021-01-11 1 days   24.0   
5     12  2021-01-12  78          5 2021-01-12 1 days   24.0   
6     13  2021-01-16  78          4 2021-01-16 4 days   96.0   
7     14  2021-01-17  78          4 2021-01-17 1 days   24.0   
8     15  2021-01-22  78          3 2021-01-22 5 days  120.0   
9     16  2021-01-24  78          3 2021-01-24 2 days   48.0   

   label_number_hours  
0                True  
1                True  
2               False  
3                True  
4               False  
5               False  
6                True  
7               False  
8                True  
9                True
```

This is what I am looking for:

df1 =

```
 index        DATE   S_N          A  timestamp  delta   time  \
0      7  2021-01-05  78          4 2021-01-05    NaT    NaN   
1      8  2021-01-07  78          3 2021-01-07 2 days   48.0   
2      9  2021-01-08  78          3 2021-01-08 1 days   24.0   
3     10  2021-01-10  78          3 2021-01-10 2 days   48.0   
4     11  2021-01-11  78          6 2021-01-11 1 days   24.0   
5     12  2021-01-12  78          5 2021-01-12 1 days   24.0   
6     13  2021-01-16  78          4 2021-01-16 4 days   96.0   
7     14  2021-01-17  78          4 2021-01-17 1 days   24.0   
8     15  2021-01-22  78          3 2021-01-22 5 days  120.0   
9     16  2021-01-24  78          3 2021-01-24 2 days   48.0   

   label_number_hours  
0                True  
1                True  
2               False  
3               False  
4               False  
5               False  
6               False  
7               False  
8                True  
9                True
```

This is my code:

df1 = df (subset = 'label_number_hours')

This is the result which I got:

```
0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
4     True
5     True
6     True
7     True
8     True
9     True
```

I am looking to be the output similar to df1 as above.

I need really to your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find indices of all `False` values with `np.where` and overwrite boolean values between the first and the last one:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([True, False, True, False, True, False, True], columns=["label_number_hours"])
df["some_other_column"] = np.random.rand(df.shape[0])

falses_idx, = np.where(~df["label_number_hours"])
if falses_idx.size > 0:
  df.iloc[falses_idx[0]:falses_idx[-1], df.columns.get_loc("label_number_hours")] = False
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I tried this and this what I got  label_number_hours
0                True
1               False
2               False
3               False
4               False
5               False
6                True
7               False
8                True
9                True

Comment: There is one "True" converted to "False" and the second one don't

Comment: Could be an issue with multiple columns. You can try the updated answer.

Comment: I just want to ask:: if there is a two 'True' in the middle of the column "label_number_hours", this code will work good as well? Remember that I have many dataframes as I mentioned in my question  so there is a possibility to be two  boolean "True" in one of dataframes  the middle of this column instead of one boalean 'True'.

Comment: The number of boolean 'True' in  the column "label_number_hours", can be unknown. I want only to change boolean 'True' to ''Faluse' if there is only one Boalean 'True' between Two 'False'. The number and location of boolean True in this column are changing from dataframe to other dataframe.

Comment: This should work as intended. All `True` values surrounded by two `False` values will be set to `False`. If the are fewer than 2 `False` values, no changes will be made.

Comment: Is there a possibility to change only the 'True' boolean to 'False' boolean if there is only one 'True' boolean between two False boolean (no more than one 'True' boolean between two False booleans). Is there any possibility for doing that?

Comment: Do you mean something like `[F, T, F] -> [F, F, F]` but `[F, T, T, F] -> [F, T, T, F]`? You could do this with `df.shift`, although this seems like a big change from the original question.

Comment: I mean how to change a booleans in datafarme, for example, from [False - True - True -     True - False - True - False -True - True - False] to [ False  -True - True - True - False - False - False - True -True - False ] . The number of True between two False is unknown and the True change to False only if it only one True between two False.

Comment: I tried to use shift, but I don't think that shift will work because as I said the number and location for Trues in the column is unknown. It is change from dataframe to another dataframe.

Comment: If you think that df.shift will work, please advise me how to use shift for this.

Comment: With `s` a boolean Series, you can run the following: `s &= s.shift(1) | s.shift(-1)`.